# How can i approximate this marble?

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

Id like to recreate this in texture node and not use an overlay. Ive done the simple mixing noise an voronoi but i cannot complete the broad wavy textures and variety of color.

[image: cloudymarble]

Comment: Wow. That's a challenging one.. :)

Comment: I thought so too. I ended uo doing a UV overlay of the original. which is cheating ha ha.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try a superposition of several *Wave Texture* nodes (it will probably need more in order to look more natural), give them a bit of *Distortion*, also distord the *Texture Coordinate* with a *Noise Texture*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: that's looking closer than what i had. thank ya. you know, i was trying to do something like this, and what i couldn't figure out was how to drive the finer texture into the same shape as the broader texture. like use the output of the wide texture to warp the smaller texture along its own shape - any ideas there?

Answer (score 0):

how about use mix node with wave texture and noise texture? I usually do by those two nodes.

and also recommend search on YouTube, for 'blender procedural marble texture'

Comment: trying your method.  thank you. YT is my first go-to on these things but i couldn't find one with quite the level of complexity i needed.